# How to call a constructor in a Junit Test in Java?

Tags: java, junit

Hello I am using Eclipse Luna and I tried to write a unittest with Junit. I want to give a value(null) to a method and it should throw an exception. The Method is a Constructor and the class has a main. What am i doing wrong. Usually I can call a Method like this Package.class.MethodName(Parameter Parameter)

Test class:

```
public class WebUntisProviderTest {

    public static URL url = null;

    @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class)
    public void WebUntisProvider() {
        final URL url = null;
        WebUntisProvider prov = new WebUntisProvider(url);

         assertNotNull("object was null" , prov.WebUntisProvider(url) );
         fail( "url must not be null.");
     }
    }
```

The tested class:

```
public class WebUntisProvider {

    private URL url;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {
        URL test = new URL("HTTP://google.com");
        System.out.println(test.getProtocol());

    }
    public WebUntisProvider(URL url) {
        if (url == null)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("url must not be null.");
        if (!url.getProtocol().equals("http") &&    !url.getProtocol().equals("https"))
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("url protocol must be http or https."); 

        this.url = url;
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Constructor is called when you do `new`, so in this line:

```
   WebUntisProvider prov = new WebUntisProvider(url);
```

Object created with `new` is always `!= null`.

You should remove below line:

```
assertNotNull("object was null" , prov.WebUntisProvider(url) );
```

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong. You can't call the constructor on the already constructed object:

```
assertNotNull("object was null" , prov.WebUntisProvider(url) );
```

Specifically: prov.WebUntisProvider(url)

I'm surprised that even compiles. You don't need to do anything more than to instantiate

```
WebUntisProvider prob= WebUntisProvider(url);
```

and run your assertions against that.

Comment: Thats the new test. 

        @Test(expected = IllegalArgumentException.class , timeout = 10)
 public void WebUntisProvider() {
  final URL url = null;
         WebUntisProvider prov = new WebUntisProvider(url);
   assertNotNull(prov);